# Display products from specific category on CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cms

I'm trying to set up a category products list on my homepage following this [tutorial](http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento/display-products-homepage).

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="27" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The above code doesn't output anything when I put it inside "Content" of my CMS home page. I'm using version 1.9.2. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you flush the cache? Do you actually have a category with the id 27?

Comment: Is there a simple way to incorporate this into a slider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using `1.9.2.[23]` or `1.9.2.[01]` with security patch `SUPEE-6788` applied, you will need to add the block to the allowed block whitelist.

1. Go to `System > Permissions > Blocks`.
2. Click 'Add new block'.
3. Enter 'catalog/product_list' and select 'Yes'.
4. Click 'Save'.
5. Clear your caches.

You should then be able to see output on the CMS page. If you don't have a menu item for `System > Permissions > Blocks` then you are probably on the older version without the patch so you're encountering a different problem.

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that when I commented above :)

Comment: Thanks to Hakala And Peter O'Callaghan, It's working for me. But i want to also dipslay layer navigation with this product list i got product list with toolbar now i want it with layer navigation also. 
so can you please help me about this.